# calling a C function in customized sort class of hadoop 2.7.4 giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, hadoop

I have customized the  Sort function of hadoop as follows:

```
conf.set("map.sort.class", "custom_map_output.CustomQuickSort");
```

I can see Hadoop using my CustomQuickSort utility to sort the keys.
Now, I want to call a C++ function to do the sorting of keys. I get
UnsatisfiedLinkError when I invoke the C++ function. My system.loadLibrary("XYZ") is getting invoked since when I provide a wrong
library name, I get a proper error message.

If I make CustomQuickSort a standalone program, the C++ function is called just fine so my JNI setup is correct and tested as part of independent Java program.

I have set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the place where libXYZ.so resides.
I have also set following (based on comments on similar questions):

```
conf.set("mapreduce.map.env", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=....")
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.env", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ...")
conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Djava.library.path= ...")
```

None of these has worked.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. It had to do with complete path to the function being called. I have created HelloWorld.h/.cpp separately from actual Hadoop sort program so the full path was not matching. Once I fixed that problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. It had to do with complete path to the function being called. i have created HelloWorld.h/.cpp separately from actual Hadoop program so the full path was not matching. Once I fixed that problem got solved.